# Improve the scrolling experience of the about me section on the new profile tab

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

On my desktop (ubuntu, several of them) most of the times I must use several attempts to scroll down in my profile view. The small vertical scrollbar is really small and hard to me for hit and not very responsive. It is important to me, because I have shortlinks to jsfiddles / plnkrs I often use as a starting point for the answers I produce. Typically it looks like this after a few attempts :

> [image]

**I have to requests** :

1) I would really like to have the vertical scrollbar a little bit broader. Or the "responsive" area (perhaps this is the problem) widened out to the whole width; and / or :

2) make the area unselectable, so if I fail in scrolling I am not selecting the background / content - it feels so stupid.

You can do this quite easily - here from [**CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/1407478) :

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I understand the "need" of a fancy "diminutive" scrollbar, a default browser scrollbar would be even worse - but to me the layout, as it is now - just really annoying. I cannot believe I am the only one who have this problem.

I will also mention that it works great on my Macbook Air, but this is because I not need to hit a "target", when I am in the zone and scroll with the fingers it works perfectly. It is "oldschool" mouse+keyboard that is the problem, and this is for me how I work, and I think millions of others still works too. I raise this issue because after 6 months, I have still trouble with doing it. First I thought I would learn to scroll naturally in the profile area by time, but I havent learned it yet - please do it a little bit more easy to us old mouse-addicts :)

Comment: Thank you @animuson, much better headline

Comment: Mouse+keyboard here, but the mouse has a scroll wheel, so...

Comment: @NormalHuman, not any mouse - and not them I am using.